# Managed and unmanaged thread behavior when creating custom window class

Tags: c#, winapi, pinvoke

**Background**

First, ignoring the question of why we need to do this, assume that I am creating a custom window using the classical Win32 pattern through C# via P/Invoke.

The general Win32 pattern is this:

1. Register a custom window class with a specified name and `WndProc`
   function
2. On a dedicated thread, create an instance of the window and
   begin a message processing loop by calling `GetMessage(...)`, translating, and dispatching.

In the unmanaged world, `WndProc` functions are invoked on the same thread that called `CreateWindow(...)`, a.k.a, the message loop thread.

**Questions**

- Is this behavior guaranteed to be the same when the thread is created in a managed context?
- If the message loop is hosted on a managed thread, will `WndProc` callbacks *always* occur on the same managed thread?
- If I retrieve the unmanaged thread ID via P/Invoke, can I always use that ID to send methods to that thread, e.g., `PostThreadMessage(...)`?

I ask only because of the notorious [warning from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/74169f59.aspx):

> An operating-system ThreadId has no fixed relationship to a managed
>   thread, because an unmanaged host can control the relationship between
>   managed and unmanaged threads.

**Sample Code**

*I tried my best to make it as small as possible. I have tested it and find that the IDs do match, but wondered if this could break given a different environment or framework version.*

```
public partial class CustomNativeWindow
{
    static WNDCLASSEX WindowClass;

    IntPtr _hwnd;

    Thread _mainThread;
    int _managedThreadId;
    uint _unmanagedThreadId;

    static CustomNativeWindow()
    {
        // Ignoring implementation here, this constructor creates
        // a window class struct with the given name and WndProc
        WindowClass = new WNDCLASSEX("ClassName", WndProc);

        NativeMethods.RegisterClassEx(WindowClass);
    }

    public CustomNativeWindow()
    {
        _mainThread = new Thread(MainThread);
        _mainThread.Start();
    }

    void MainThread()
    {
        _hwnd = NativeMethods.CreateWindowEx( /* ... */ );

        CustomNativeWindow.RegisterHwnd(_hwnd);

        // We grab these values before we start our message loop
        _managedThreadId = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        _unmanagedThreadId = NativeMethods.GetCurrentThread();

        MSG msg;
        int result;
        while((result = NativeMethods.GetMessage(out msg, _hwnd, 0, 0)) != 0)
        {
            NativeMethods.TranslateMessage(ref msg);
            NativeMethods.DispatchMessage(ref msg);
        }
    }

    // Although not so obvious, this method is invoked on the MainThread thread
    // while GetMessage call is blocking
    static IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hWnd, uint msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        // Since WndProc is defined for the class, not the instance, assume we have
        // some way to retrieve the specific instance this method is invoked on
        var windowInstance = CustomNativeWindow.LookupHwnd(hWnd);

        if (windowInstance._managedThreadId != Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
            throw new Exception("Is this even possible?");

        if (windowInstance._unmanagedThreadId != NativeMethods.GetCurrentThread())
            throw new Exception("How about this?");

        return NativeMethods.DefWindowProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure that this question has been asked here many times before. Please search for prior art.

Comment: Can you not even provide a small hint at the end of *why* you believe that going down this route is the only way to solve your problem? Are you sure you've ruled out all possible "less hacky" solutions?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, there are indeed many questions that address the mapping behavior of managed to unmanaged threads, but none that deal with what thread WndProc will be invoked on when CreateWindow is called from a managed thread. My gumption is that it will always be the same unmanaged thread, and that unmanaged thread will always map to the same managed. Just looking for and explanation why that can be guaranteed.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, we do have a reason, I promise: do not be unbelieving, but believe! (a lame user-name joke). The short explanation is that we have a legacy application we are connecting to that sends windows messages to windows of a particular Win32 class name. There is no way in C# to define this except for P/Invoking. From there we require the standard Win32 ability to receive and process messages from the legacy application, and prefer to do the entire thing in C#.

Comment: It does not work differently in a managed app, they do not add any mechanism that hops the callback to the window procedure onto another thread.  Would both be very buggy and very expensive.  *Never* use PostThreadMessage() on a thread that creates a window, the message will disappear without trace whenever the app pumps another message loop.  Like the ones used to allow resizing a window or display a dialog.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen that question answered. The answer is that it is called on the same unmanaged thread that created the window, because that's the Win32 rule. And that unmanaged thread is mapped to the same managed thread.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, for the life of me I could not find the right search terms to find a matching question. Even while drafting, I clicked on every link of a possibly related question and could not find it. If you are able to post the SO question that this duplicates, I will gladly retract this one.

Comment: Well, anyone can choose to *host* the CLR and play any threading games they like, provided they're willing to meet the requirements of the hosting interfaces. Not a concern when your code is directly running as an EXE, and hopefully you're not writing windows message pump code to run within SQL Server, which is the most common "other" host that you'll encounter.

Comment: Also, doesn't the code sample for [`NativeWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.nativewindow(v=vs.110).aspx) show a managed example which sets a specific OS class name?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, looks like you are right regarding registering custom window class names. A couple of old SO questions seem to have led me down the wrong path (needing to use P/Invoke). And for the record, our application is run in a hosted CLR, so I was trying to find evidence that I could hang my hat on regarding managed / unmanaged thread behavior.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever @DavidHefferman - last comment (trying not to have a long convo here in proper SO form) - the `NativeWindow` class does not appear to allow registering custom class names, rather it only seems to allow using existing OS window class names. The crux of the question here is whether or not a single unmanaged thread (which has predictable behavior) would ever be shared by one or more managed threads. The answer in the linked question indicates de-facto, no.